# Display date and time from datetimepicker

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, datetimepicker

I want to display the date and time selected from date picker using `ng-model`. I have a template and am using date and time pickers from it. Right now, I have the below code:

```
<div class="form-group" id="data_1">
    <label class="font-noraml">Date:</label>
    <div class="input-group date" >
        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></span><input type="text" class="form-control" value="2014/06/09">
    </div>
</div>
<label class="font-noraml">Time:</label>
<div class="input-group clockpicker" data-autoclose="true">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" value="09:30">
    <span class="input-group-addon">
        <span class="fa fa-clock-o"></span>
    </span>
</div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#data_1 .input-group.date').datepicker({
            todayBtn: "linked",
            keyboardNavigation: false,
            forceParse: false,
            calendarWeeks: true,
            autoclose: true,
            format: "yyyy/mm/dd"
        });

        $('.clockpicker').clockpicker();
    });
</script>
```

This is working well (I'm able to select both date and time) but I want to display the selected date and time below, when user selects them. Can anyone provide the solution for this?

Comment: You might want to take a look at this https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/datepicker if you want to get the bootstrap components working with angular.

Answer (score 0):

try using below code

```
    $(txtControlName).datepicker({
        showOtherMonths: true,
        selectOtherMonths: true,
        minDate: "here give your min date",
        maxDate: "maximum date",
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        yearRange: "1900:2100",
        defaultDate: +1
    });
```

so now user will only be able to select date between min and max

Answer (score 0):

Using jquery with angular is not a very good idea. You are bound to run into problems. I think you should use [ui-bootstrap](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/)'s datepicker.

Comment: what kind of problems are you likely to run into? I have been using both at the same time with no issue

Comment: I am not saying they cant be used with each other at all. BUT whenever it is possible to use angular's stuff, why use jquery like in this question. I have seen use cases where angular overrides jquery functionalities etc. If you google jquery with angularjs you'll find a lot of opinions stating angularjs and jquery dont work well together.

Comment: I had a look. The one I found is totally contrived to suit the point of view. http://tech.zumba.com/2014/08/02/angularjs-forget-jquery/ As long as you know what each is supposed to do it shouldn't be an issue

Comment: Yes that is true I myself use jquery only when I can't find an implementation in angular. But the point is using them in conjunction as much as possible.